# Magento : How to Alter Delete Confirm Message?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, messages, delete

I want to alter the message of delete confirm in custom extension and I don't know how. Someone can help me?

[image]

**DutyController.php**

```
class Nothing_Duty_Adminhtml_DutyController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu("duty/duty")->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty  Manager"),Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Manager"));
        return $this;
    }


    public function indexAction() 
    {
        $this->_title($this->__("Duty"));
        $this->_title($this->__("Teste Criação de Grid"));

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }


    public function editAction()
    {               
        $this->_title($this->__("Editar Item"));

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        $model = Mage::getModel("duty/cake")->load($id);
        if ($model->getId()) {
            Mage::register("duty_data", $model);
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu("duty/duty");
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Manager"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Manager"));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Description"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Description"));
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock("duty/adminhtml_duty_edit"))->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock("duty/adminhtml_duty_edit_tabs"));
            $this->renderLayout();
        } 
        else {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError(Mage::helper("duty")->__("Item does not exist."));
            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
        }
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__("Novo item"));

        $id   = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        $model  = Mage::getModel("duty/cake")->load($id);

        $data = Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        Mage::register("duty_data", $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu("duty/duty");

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Manager"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Manager"));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Description"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Duty Description"));


        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock("duty/adminhtml_duty_edit"))->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock("duty/adminhtml_duty_edit_tabs"));

        $this->renderLayout();

    }

    public function saveAction()
    {

        $post_data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();


        if ($post_data) {

            try {   

                $model = Mage::getModel("duty/cake")
                ->addData($post_data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
                ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("O item foi salvo com sucesso!"));
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setDutyData(false);

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("back")) {
                    $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }

                $this->_redirect("*/*/");
                return;
            } 
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setDutyData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
                return;
            }

        }
        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
    }



    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam("id") > 0 ) {
            try {
                $model = Mage::getModel("duty/cake");
                $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))->delete();
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item foi deletado com sucesso!"));
                $this->_redirect("*/*/");
            } 
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect("*/*/delete", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
    }


    public function massRemoveAction()
    {
        try {
            $ids = $this->getRequest()->getPost('codigos', array());
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $model = Mage::getModel("duty/cake");
                $model->setId($id)->delete();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item removido com sucesso!"));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }


    public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'arquivocsv.csv';
        $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('duty/adminhtml_duty_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
    } 


    public function exportExcelAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'arquivoxml.xml';
        $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('duty/adminhtml_duty_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getExcelFile($fileName));
    }
}
```

**Edit.php**

```
class Nothing_Duty_Block_Adminhtml_Duty_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_objectId = "codigo";
        $this->_blockGroup = "duty";
        $this->_controller = "adminhtml_duty";
        $this->_updateButton("save", "label", Mage::helper("duty")->__("Salvar Item"));
        $this->_updateButton("delete", "label", Mage::helper("duty")->__("Deletar Item"));

        $this->_addButton("saveandcontinue", array(
            "label"     => Mage::helper("duty")->__("Salvar e Continuar a Editar"),
            "onclick"   => "saveAndContinueEdit()",
            "class"     => "save",
        ), -100);



        $this->_formScripts[] = "

        function saveAndContinueEdit(){
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry("duty_data") && Mage::registry("duty_data")->getId() ){

            return Mage::helper("duty")->__("Editar Item '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry("duty_data")->getId()));

        } 
        else{

            return Mage::helper("duty")->__("Adicionar");

        }
    }
}
```

ps: The function of this button is DeleteAction

Comment: buttons are defined in `Edit.php` file which  extends class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container` , check that file

Comment: I updated the question. I tried changing the Edit.php, but what I tried does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following, just below `parent::__construct();`, in `Nothing_Duty_Block_Adminhtml_Duty_Edit::__construct()`:

```
$objId = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->_objectId);

if (! empty($objId)) {
    $this->_updateButton('delete', null, array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Delete'),
        'class'     => 'delete',
        'onclick'   => 'deleteConfirm(\''
            . Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape(
                Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Are you sure you want to do this?')
            )
            .'\', \''
            . $this->getDeleteUrl()
            . '\')',
    ));
}
```

Then, you can edit the "Are you sure..." string.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!